# Gallary cropping not working in HTC One,Device version 4.4?

Tags: android, gallery

In my application i want to get image from gallary and cropping that image and set the crop image to imageview.By using the following code to get the image from gallary

```
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
           photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
           startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 0);
```

After taht in onActivityResult method to the data by using the follaowing code.And after that crop the image by using default application.

```
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
startCrop(selectedImagePath);
```

and this is the get path method

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) 
        {
           try{
         String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
         Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
         int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         if(cursor.getString(column_index)==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(EmailRegistrationActivity.this, "Please Select Image from Gallery",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return "";
            }else
            {
                Log.e("return string======",cursor.getString(column_index));
                return cursor.getString(column_index);

            }
           }catch(Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
               Toast.makeText(EmailRegistrationActivity.this, "Please Select Image from Gallery",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return "";
           }
        }
```

And this is the cropping method

```
public  void startCrop(String m_Path)
 {
  Intent m_cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
     // indicate image type and Uri
     m_cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(m_Path)), "image/*");
     // set crop properties
     m_cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
     // indicate aspect of desired crop
     m_cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
     m_cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
     // indicate output X and Y
     m_cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
     m_cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
     Uri cropUri = getTempFile();
     strImagePath_Crop=cropUri.getPath();
  m_cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cropUri);
     // retrieve data on return
     m_cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
     // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
     startActivityForResult(m_cropIntent, 535);
 }
```

And after that in onactivityresult method i have get the data from another switch case by sing the following code

```
    try{
         Log.e("strImagePath_Crop======",strImagePath_Crop);
         Bitmap bitmap=getCorrectBitmap(strImagePath_Crop);
         profilepic.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(new RoundedImageView(getApplicationContext()).getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, 350)));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This code is working in samsungs4 and galaxy nexus also.But In **htc one** it is not working.It return null value after cropping the image.What is the solution fot that.Please guide me.Thanks In Advance..

Comment: Any help with this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove   `m_cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);`